# Problem after install CodeRush and ReFactor

Tags: visual-studio, coderush, refactorpro

I have installed CodeRush and ReFactor package but i don't see any changes on my Visual Studio 2010 ide. I check add-in and extension manager but i don't see anything belong CodeRush or ReFactor. Do i have to do some extra settings for it ? How can i understand it is installed on Visual Studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you've installed CodeRush Xpress instead of the full CodeRush?

CodeRush Xpress has no 'DevExpress' menu and as such it may well look like nothing has changed.

Check this by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> shortcut. If CodeRush is functioning, then this should launch the options menu.

It is also possible that the install did not complete correctly for some reason.
I recommend, uninstalling and reinstalling as a first measure.

If this does not succeed, then I recommend contacting support directly via either `support@devexpress.com` or better yet, by filing a bug report in [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Comment: I have installed below link. I didn't see anything after Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O .
http://go.devexpress.com/DevExpressDownload_CodeRush3.aspx

Comment: This install will allow you to install either CodeRush Xpress or registered or trial editions of either CodeRush or Refactor Pro.

So much will depend on the options you chose. I'd certainly raise a support issue if I were you.